# Drawing on canvas in loop points are off

Tags: javascript, google-maps, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw on top of a canvas, but the points that I draw end up being in the wrong location.  I know it is something related to the loop (and most likely variable scope and the sequence of events) because when I draw each of the data points one at a time, they show up in the correct place.  As soon as I loop over an array of more than one element, the points do not end up the in the right place (I am drawing them over a google maps map - yes, I have used their javascript api but I am going to do something more custom than their api will enable.  But using their api to map points is how I have verified that my points draw in the correct location when done one at a time, yet end up in the wrong spots when I loop over the array).

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(data[0].location.lat, data[0].location.long));
map.setZoom(15);
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var topLeft = bounds.getNorthEast();
var bottomRight = bounds.getSouthWest();
var left = topLeft.lat();
var top = topLeft.lng();
var right = bottomRight.lat();
var bottom = bottomRight.lng();
var height = Math.abs(top - bottom);
var width = Math.abs(left - right);


canvas = $('#mapCanvas').get(0);
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;

context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var radius = 10;

var fromTop;
var fromLeft;
var ratioTop;
var ratioLeft;
var centerX;
var centerY;

_.each(data, function(point) {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.location.lat, point.location.long);
  if (bounds.contains(latLng)) { // this point lies in the map, plot it on the canvas!
    // calculate distance from top left
    fromTop = Math.abs(top - point.location.long);
    fromLeft = Math.abs(left - point.location.lat);
    ratioTop = fromTop / height;
    ratioLeft = fromLeft / width;

    centerX = Math.floor(ratioLeft * canvasWidth);
    centerY = Math.floor(ratioTop * canvasHeight);

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  }
});
```

Note - the data array contains objects like this:

```
{ _id: 5362a54a038a09d66ac9b36d,
location: { lat: 46.368619, long: -109.027793 } }
```

Here is an illustration of the problem:  The green dots are drawn on the canvas, the yellow and purple ones are drawn using google's api.  Notice that the first dot drawn overlaps with the correct location.  Also, as mentioned before, if I just draw the 3rd dot individually, or any of them individually, then they show up in the correct place.

[image: Canvas drawing off]

I also put together a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68Gy4/)

Comment: (from/ratio)+(Left/Top) and centerX/Y are vars of the function, do not define them outside. It's not the root cause but it will be cleaner. Could you show working code as well, and describe or join picture of 'not in the right place' ?

Comment: Yep - done.  And I initially had those defined inside, I factored it out to make sure that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before reading this answer sit down and promisse not to bang your head on a wall ! :-)

Your code is perfectly fine, you just considered that latitude was to be matched with 'x' coordinates, and longitude with 'y' coordinates.
But in fact the other way around is right : look again the definitions if in doubt.

If you look at your 'wrong' result, it's just the right result rotated and scaled.

So just by 1) swapping here and there longitude with latitude, and 2) taking the symmetric of the longitude, you have a perfect match with google's result :

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/68Gy4/2/

```
// during the init : 
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var topLeft = bounds.getNorthEast();
var bottomRight = bounds.getSouthWest();
var left = topLeft.lng();
var top = topLeft.lat();
var right = bottomRight.lng();
var bottom = bottomRight.lat();
var height = Math.abs(top - bottom);
var width = Math.abs(left - right);

// and in your each loop : 
var fromTop = Math.abs(top - point.location.lat);
var fromLeft =  Math.abs(left - point.location.long);
var ratioTop = fromTop / height;
var ratioLeft = fromLeft / width;

var centerX = canvasWidth - Math.floor(ratioLeft * canvasWidth);
var centerY = Math.floor(ratioTop * canvasHeight);
```

perfectly ok result :

[image]

Comment: *doh! I cant believe it!  I think I am getting a little confused now though - for example, fromTop = Math.abs(left - point.location.lat); - that feels wrong.  That should be called fromLeft?  You divide it by the width to determine the ratio from the top?  Please explain

Comment: Ok, ok :-) i took the (finally not so long) time to get names right, see my edit.